# XML - backspace code

Tags: xml, backspace

How do I add a backspace code to my code that will delete the o from `Hello`?

For example, `Hello` would become `Hell`.

I have tried to use `&#8;`, but it is illegal in XML.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain how you intend to use all this in more details? What does 'do backspace' mean?

Comment: by backspace I mean buttun on your keyboard, it is button that is used for deleting for example your text. I am filling out my `.docx` template for database, and if any of my variables will be empty it will make empty line, and I want to delete that empty line by XML code or tag

Comment: With all due respect (and appreciation for that detailed explanation of that pesky 'Backspace' button mechanic; always missed it), you expect way too much from an XML element. I see that you've mentioned filling '.docx' by PHP; could you show this code instead?

Answer (score 1):

Backspace as a control character exists from the days of devices like teletypes, and from paper tape where physical deletion of a character was impossible. As far as I know there are very few applications today that will recognize and interpret the semantics of a backspace in a character stream. That's why it's not supported in XML. If you want to delete a character, simply delete the character.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get it in a string or other sliceable type, there's always [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python); in this case, you'd do something like:

```
x = 'hello'
'hello'
x[:-1]
'hell'
x[:4]
'hell'
```

Comment: and what if I get empty line in `.docx`, how do I delete empty line from my ziped xml file? ... because I am filling my `.docx` from DB by PHP and if any variable is empty I get blanc line... thats what I want to delete

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. So you're trying to export to a .docx? Could you show code or something, as I really don't get what you're asking.