# Delete Last Character with Curses?

Tags: python, curses

I have been looking everywhere to figure out how to delete the last character on my curses prompt with my backspace.

My backspace is returning `^?` or the ASCII code `127`, which I can catch properly, however, I can't find the command to delete the `^?` + last char that was typed, and Ideally, I would like to delete all the back up to the beginning of the prompt with backspace

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code which implements your prompt?

Answer (score -1):

I do not know a lot about `curses`, but if I understand you correctly one part of your question is that you do not know how to remove the last char of a string?

To pop the last char of a string:

```
st =  "abcdefghij"
st = st[:-1]
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15478161/2173793)

Maybe you can try something like [this](http://nullege.com/codes/search/curses.KEY_BACKSPACE#highlighter_700959):

```
elif c == curses.KEY_DC or c == curses.KEY_BACKSPACE or c == 127:
            cur_line = cur_line[0:-1]
            stdscr.addstr(pos_type, (pos["x"] + pos_msg + len(cur_line)), " ".encode(code))        
            stdscr.addstr(pos_type, pos_con, "                     ".encode(code))
```

I do hope that this is helpful.