# How to remove last char from string in IronPyhon?

Tags: ironpython

How to remove last char from string in IronPyhon ?

I am looking for a Substring method or sth similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove final character from string (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478127/remove-final-character-from-string-python)

Comment: Does `somestring[:-1]` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somestring[:-1] is a correct answer also for IronPython