# How to replace the last 14 number with 0s using regular expressions?

Tags: python

I am displaying data from a file by using a regular expression. I want to use:

```
ID=02141592cc0000000700000000000000 
ID=02141592cc000000010000000e9489c5 
ID=02141592cc0000000500000000000000 
ID=02141592cc000000010000000e9489c5
ID=02141592cc0000000400000000000000 
ID=02141592cc000000010000000e9489c5
```

I am using this funtion to extract data:

```
data = OrderedDict({

    'data': r'\b\s\sID=(\w{32})0*',
   })

def Extract_List_Data_Info_Based_On_Regular_Expression(Log_File):
    # print(re_key)
    for re_key in data.keys():

        print(re_key)
        re_value = data[re_key]
        fsrc = open(Log_File, 'r')
        buff = fsrc.read()
        list_info = re.findall(re_value, buff)
        print(list_info)
```

My goal is to extract data, then modify the last 14 numbers with 0. I want write the modification in the file. For example: this `ID=02141592cc000000010000000e9489c5`  then I want to modify it it to `ID=02141592cc0000000100000000000000`

Comment: @Austin  Thank you I edit it last 14.

Comment: @JackMoody could you give me more exlpanation? It is not clear

Comment: my answer wasn’t exactly right. You probably want to use `my_string = my_string[:-14] + “0”*14`. This will take your original string, cut off the last 14 characters and then add 14 zeros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove final character from string (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478127/remove-final-character-from-string-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you

```
s1 = "ID=02141592cc000000010000000e9489c5"
print s1[:-14] + '0'*14
```

Answer (score 0):

I will write another answer, similar to Amit with `repace()`

```
ID = ID.replace(ID[len(ID)-14:], "0"*14)
```

That's the same idea behind. You don't need regular expression to do what you wanna do :)