# How to erase letters at any position in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, position, erase

For example, my `String = 'xx22xx_1x_xxxx-xxxx'`, `x` can be any letters.
Now I want to delete the first two positions letters `xx` and seventh position `1`, in order to get a `NewString = '22xx_x_xxxx-xxxx'`.
Any function to erase letters at specific positions?

Comment: this is trivial in python using slicing. what have you tried?

Comment: Maybe you could give us a more detailed description of your problem. There are several ways for achieving this, so it's a bit unclear what would be best in your case ...

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you need to construct a *new* string. Use slicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def erase(string, positions):
    return "".join([y for x,y in enumerate(string) if x not in positions])
```

demo:

```
>>> s='xx22xx_1x_xxxx-xxxx'
>>> erase(s, (0,1,7))
'22xx_x_xxxx-xxxx'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to implement slicing!  It is not just applicable to strings.

Example from this question: [Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

```
>>> x = "Hello World!"
>>> x[2:]
'llo World!'
>>> x[:2]
'He'
>>> x[:-2]
'Hello Worl'
>>> x[-2:]
'd!'
>>> x[2:-2]
'llo Worl'
```

To Answer your question do this!

**Removing the first two "xx"**

```
NewString = String[2:]
```

**Removing the 1**

```
NewString = NewString[:5]+NewString[7:]
```