# Check a string for all or 3 consecutive characters of another string? Regex python NOT case-sensitive

Tags: python, regex, string

Say I have `string1 = "Helloworld33"`

I want to be able to check a `string2` so that it does not contain any three character part of `string1`.

`string2` could be any set of characters of any length.

For example:

```
string1 = "Helloworld33"

string2 = "ello" (invalid)

          "3hi3" (valid)

          "H e l l o" (valid)

          "Hw3" (valid)

          "I_^&_rld_37482" (invalid)
```

How can this be done through regex in python? Or is there a way to do it without?

EDIT: Also, is there a way to do it so it is **NOT** case-sensitive?

Much thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This could be accomplished inefficiently using substring and `in`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problems of this kind (mind bending iteration) tend to have elegant functional solutions:

```
def not3(string2, string1):
    if len(string2) < 3:  return True    # reaching here, the sequence wasn't found
    if string2[:3] in string1: return False      # test beginning of string2 for existence in string1
    return not3(string2[1:], string1)  # recurse from next char of string2
```

Comment: So, is there a way to make your function not case-sensitive?

Comment: Yes, you can change the second line to: `if string2[:3].lower() in string1.lower()`. That is, check the lower case version of both strings (or upper case)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module:

```
import difflib
def solve(strs, match, n):
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, strs, match)
    return all(item.size < n for item in s.get_matching_blocks())
... 
>>> solve('Helloworld33', 'ello', 3)
False
>>> solve('Helloworld33', '3hi3', 3)
True
>>> solve('Helloworld33', 'H e l l o', 3)
True
>>> solve('Helloworld33', 'Hw3', 3)
True
>>> solve('Helloworld33', 'I_^&_rld_37482', 3)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create all triplets from `string1` and then check if any of these triplets occur in `string2`:

```
string1 = "Helloworld33"
triplets = set([string1[i:i+3] for i in range(len(string1) - 2)])
result = not any(t in string2 for t in triplets)
```

Answer (score 1):

Find all substrings of length 3 and check whether any are in the second string.

```
valid = not any(sub.group(1) in string2 for sub in re.finditer(r"(?=(.{3}))", string1))
```

Here is a demonstration: http://ideone.com/T77mHn