# python regular expression, pulling all letters out

Tags: python, regex

Is there a better way to pull `A` and `F` from this: `A13:F20`

```
a="A13:F20"
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\D+\d+\D+')
matches = re.search(pattern, a)
num = matches.group(0)
print num[0]
print num[len(num)-1]
```

output

`A`
`F`

note: the digits are of unknown length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use regular expressions, or `re` at all. Assuming you want just letters to remain, you could do something like this:

```
a = "A13:F20"
a = filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), a)
```

Comment: What is the equivalent of your code but for numbers? Some like `filter(lambda x: x.isnumber(), a)`. Could you please link to the reference page. Thanks

Comment: @jason_cant_code: you're looking for `filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), a)`. [Here's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) the reference page.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple list comprehension, as a filter and get only the alphabets from the actual string.

```
print [char for char in input_string if char.isalpha()]
# ['A', 'F']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]', a, re.IGNORECASE)
['A', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub`:

```
>>> a="A13.F20"
>>> re.sub(r'[^A-Z]', '', a)     # Remove everything apart from A-Z
'AF'
>>> re.sub(r'[A-Z]', '', a)      # Remove A-Z
'13.20'
>>>
```

Comment: @RichieHindle I couldn't read the mind since the desired output wasn't posted.

Comment: sorry i just edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @RichieHindle I'm sure, I could have!  Thanks for enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with strings that all have the same format, you can just cut out substrings:

```
a="A13:F20"
print a[0], a[4]
```

More on python slicing in this answer: 
[Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)