# Python uuid4, How to limit the length of Unique chars

Tags: python

In Python, I am using uuid4() method to create a unique char set. But I can not find a way to limit that to 10 or 8 characters. Is there any way?

`uuid4()`

`ffc69c1b-9d87-4c19-8dac-c09ca857e3fc`

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is standard format for UUID. If you want to change it to 10 or 8 character, you can treat it as string and get only 10 character.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can then generate a short UUID with [shortuuid](https://pypi.org/project/shortuuid/):

```
import shortuuid
shortuuid.uuid()
'vytxeTZskVKR7C7WgdSP3d'
```

### Native solution with big risk of collision:

Try :

```
x = uuid4()
str(x)[:8]
```

Output :

```
"ffc69c1b"
```

[How do I get a substring of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

Comment: uuid4()[:10]
`ERROR UUID object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: You must to use str().

Comment: will this increase the collision chances?

Comment: @DavidC Yes, this will increase the collision chances.

Comment: This is a bad answer, the UUID as a whole is what guarantees uniqueness, truncating it introduces the possibility of collisions which defeats the purpose of using UUID. A better idea would be to generate a cryptographic token with the desired length. This also has the possibility of collisions, but I imagine it would be much less than a truncated UUID.

Comment: If you cut only first eight characters you remove unique aspect of uuid which defies reason why you use it. There are other Python tools to generate random alphanumeric string of given length.

Comment: The question was "a way to limit that to 10 or 8 characters", maybe the collision rate is not a problem for the op.

Answer (score 13):

You can use **shortuuid** package.

```
pip install shortuuid
```

then it would be similar to UUID package.

```
import shortuuid
shortuuid.uuid()
```

**Output**

```
'vytxeTZskVKR7C7WgdSP3d'
```

Custom Length UUID

```
shortuuid.ShortUUID().random(length=22)
```

**Output**

```
'RaF56o2r58hTKT7AYS9doj'
```

**Source** - https://pypi.org/project/shortuuid/

Comment: you cannot change the length of a uuid. `shortuuid.ShortUUID().random(length=22)` does generate a cryptographically secure random string as per the documentation you provided but *this is not a uuid anymore.*

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers do not provide a UUID, either because they truncate the string or because they didn't generate a UUID to begin with. According to [the documentation,](https://pypi.org/project/shortuuid/) if you truncate the string "[t]he IDs won’t be universally unique any longer [...]" and the documentation describes `ShortUUID().random()` to generate a cryptographically secure string instead of a UUID.

However, you can change the UUID length indirectly by changing the number of characters in the alphabet. In the implementation of `ShortUUID.encoded_length()` you can see that the UUID length is `int(math.ceil(16 * math.log(256) / math.log(len(alphabet))))`. You can change the alphabet by `shortuuid.set_alphabet()`.

The more characters in the alphabet, the shorter the UUID can be and *still* be unique.

Comment: potentially interesting: https://hashids.org/python/