# Program to make an acronym with a period in between each letter

Tags: python, function

so i'm trying to make a program in Python PyScripter 3.3  that takes input, and converts the input into an acronym. This is what i'm looking for.

your input: center of earth

programs output: C.O.E.

I don't really know how to go about doing this, I am looking for not just the right answer, but an explanation of why certain code is used, thanks..

What I have tried so far:

```
def first_letters(lst):
        return [s[:1] for s in converted]



def main():

     lst = input("What is the phrase you wish to convert into an acronym?")
     converted = lst.split().upper()
```

Beyond here I am not really sure where to go, so far I know I need to captialize the input, split it into separate words, and then beyond that im not sure where to go...

Comment: You can try looking at this post: [Python SubString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I have the feeling that you do know how to do it - you just haven't laid out the specific steps of the algorithm you use. Try to go through it on paper, using simple steps that have a Python equivalent (like built-ins, string methods, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Python 3.

```
>>> s = 'center of earth'
>>> print(*(word[0] for word in s.upper().split()), sep='.', end='.\n')
C.O.E.
```

1. `s = 'center of earth'` - Assign the string.
2. `s.upper()` - Make the string uppercase. This goes before `split()` because `split()` returns a `list` and `upper()` doesn't work on `list`s.
3. `.split()` - Split the uppercased string into a list.
4. `for word in` - Iterate through each element of the created `list`.
5. `word[0]` - The first letter of each word.
6. `*` - Unpack this generator and pass each element as an argument to the `print` function.
7. `sep='.'` - Specify a period to separate each printed argument.
8. `end='.\n'` - Specify a period and a newline to print after all the arguments.
9. `print` - Print it.

---

As an alternative:

```
>>> s = 'center of earth'
>>> '.'.join(filter(lambda x: x.isupper(), s.title())) + '.'
'C.O.E.'
```

1. `s = 'center of earth'` - Assign the string.
2. `s.title()` - Change the string to Title Case.
3. `filter` - Filter the string, retaining only those elements that are approved by a predicate (the `lambda` below).
4. `lambda x: x.isupper()` - Define an anonymous inline function that takes an argument `x` and returns whether `x` is uppercase.
5. `'.'.join` - Join all the filtered elements with a `'.'`.
6. `+ '.'` - Add a period to the end.

Note that this one returns a string instead of simply printing it to the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "center of earth"
>>> re.sub('[a-z ]+', '.', s.title())
'C.O.E.'

>>> "".join(i[0].upper() + "." for i in s.split())
'C.O.E.'
```

Comment: Or, more simply, `".".join(i[0].upper() for i in s.split())`

Comment: I am very new to python, and after searching the forums for this exact question, I am looking for some help that would include an explanation, not just an answer. I don't want an answer, I want to understand how to go about doing this so I don't need to ask for help in the future.

Comment: @IonutHulub, that leaves off the final '.'

Comment: @JohnLaRooy so just add `+ '.'` at the end. It's a matter of personal taste I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an explanation and not just an answer:

```
>>> s = 'center of earth'
>>> s = s.split()  # split it into words
>>> s
['center', 'of', 'earth']
>>> s = [i[0] for i in s]  # get only the first letter or each word
>>> s
['c', 'o', 'e']
>>> s = [i.upper() for i in s]  # convert the letters to uppercase
>>> s
['C', 'O', 'E']
>>> s = '.'.join(s)  # join the letters into a string
>>> s
'C.O.E'
>>> s = s + '.'  # add the dot at the end
>>> s
'C.O.E.'
```