# How to cut initial part of a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How do I strip character 'A' from the beginning of a string if the string starts with 'A'?

```
"AsomethingAsomething" output should be "somethingAsomething"
"somethingAsomething" output should be "somethingAsomething"
```

(Using Python 3.x)

Comment: Have a look at [lstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) -> `'AsomethingAsomethingAsomething'.lstrip('A')`

Comment: What did u try so far?..Have u heard about string slicing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = "AsomethingAsomethingAsomething"
```

<strike>`s[s.find('A')+1:]`</strike>

```
s.lstrip('A')
```

Comment: If the string doesn't start with an 'A' this will have the wrong output.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, you are right. I read question in rush.

Answer (score 1):

Combine some logic and `str` methods and slice:

```
if some_string.startswith('A'):
    some_string = some_string[1:]
```

Or even better, just use `some_string = some_string.lstrip('A')` as proposed in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

with lstrip

```
string = "AsomethingAsomethingAsomething"
string.lstrip('A')
```