# Find substrings in string using python

Tags: python

I have data

```
vk.com/idefiks
vk.com/id211452033
vk.com/id211452033
vk.com/id165402000
vk.com/id_lizalizaelizaveta
```

I need to get all url, where are numbers after `id`.
If I use

```
if '/id' in url:
```

it returns all strings.
How can I return only `id` with number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `re` module. for example:

```
import re
s = """
vk.com/idefiks
vk.com/id211452033
vk.com/id211452033
vk.com/id165402000
vk.com/id_lizalizaelizaveta
"""
p = re.compile('/id\d+')
print p.findall(s)
```

The output will be:

```
['/id211452033', '/id211452033', '/id165402000']
```

PS: if want to remove `/` in the result, just update regular expression to `/(id\d+)`. that is because, `findall` just returns the captured groups

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution :

```
x = "vk.com/idefiks"
x[6:]
```

This will give : `/idefiks`

If you want to omit the `/` use `x[7:]`.

You may do it using `re` too, but that's not required for this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if '/id' in url:
    result = url.split('/id')[-1]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for item in data:
    listItem = item.split('/')
    strId = listItem[1]
```

try this