# How to slice numbers into parts of three

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

How can i slice and split list like this
A = ['105200166', '177288399'] into
[['105', '200', '166'],['177','288',399']

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> thelist =  ['105200166', '177288399']
>>> result = []
>>> for item in thelist:
...     tmp = []
...     sets = (len(item) + 2) // 3
...     for i in range(0, sets):
...         start = i * 3
...         end = start + 3
...         tmp.append(item[start:end])
...     result.append(tmp)
...
>>> result
[['105', '200', '166'], ['177', '288', '399']]
```