# Web Scraping - How to get a specific part of a weblink

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

i have the following link:
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jAc7OJyyQboJ:**https://cooking.nytimes.com/learn-to-cook**+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk

I have multiple links in a dataset. Each link is of same pattern. I want to get a specific part of the link, for the above link i would be the bold part of the link above. I want text starting from 2nd http to before first + sign.

I don't know how to do so using regex. I am working in python. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each link has the same pattern you do not need regex. You can use [string.find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) and [string cutting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

```
link = "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jAc7OJyyQboJ:https://cooking.nytimes.com/learn-to-cook+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk"

# This finds the second occurrence of "https://" and returns the position
second_https = link.find("https://", link.find("https://")+1)
# Index of the end of the link
end_of_link = link.find("+")

new_link = link[second_https:end_of_link]

print(new_link)
```

This will return "https://cooking.nytimes.com/learn-to-cook" and will work if the link follows the same pattern as described (it is the second *https://* in the link and ends with *+* sign)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **[urlparse (Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) or [urlparse (Python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)**  and a little bit of **re**gex:

```
import re
from urlparse import urlparse

url_example = "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jAc7OJyyQboJ:https://cooking.nytimes.com/learn-to-cook+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk"
parsed = urlparse(url_example)
result = re.findall('https?.*', parsed.query)[0].split('+')[0]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
https://cooking.nytimes.com/learn-to-cook
```