# Stripping all but the last 2 letters of each string in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to work out how to take a list of strings, and remove all of the letters in each string apart from the last two. Could someone please help? An example being ["Bob", "Steve", "Jeremy"], I only want the "ob", "ve", and "my". This has to work regardless of how long each string is. I only know how to do this with a specific sized string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[i[-2:] for i in ["Bob", "Steve", "Jeremy"]]
```