# Is there a way to substring, which is between two words in the string in Python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, substring

My question is more or less similar to:
[Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but it's more specifically oriented.
How can I get a par of a string which is located between two known words in the initial string.

Example:

```
mySrting = "this is the initial string"
Substring = "initial"
```

knowing that "the" and "string" are the two known words in the string that can be used to get the substring.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want the string between two known words? Why are the spaces not part of the `Substring`?

Comment: Furthermore what should happen if `'the'` and `'string'` occur multiple times in `mySrting`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then it should maybe show a list of strings.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and the spaces can be included in the two other words 'the ' and ' string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with simple string manipulation here. [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) is your best friend there, as it will tell you the position of a substring within a string; and you can also start searching somewhere later in the string:

```
>>> myString = "this is the initial string"
>>> myString.index('the')
8
>>> myString.index('string', 8)
20
```

Looking at the slice `[8:20]`, we already get close to what we want:

```
>>> myString[8:20]
'the initial '
```

Of course, since we found the beginning position of `'the'`, we need to account for its length. And finally, we might want to strip whitespace:

```
>>> myString[8 + 3:20]
' initial '
>>> myString[8 + 3:20].strip()
'initial'
```

Combined, you would do this:

```
startIndex = myString.index('the')
substring = myString[startIndex + 3 : myString.index('string', startIndex)].strip()
```

---

If you want to look for matches multiple times, then you just need to repeat doing this while looking only at the rest of the string. Since `str.index` will only ever find the first match, you can use this to scan the string very efficiently:

```
searchString = 'this is the initial string but I added the relevant string pair a few more times into the search string.'
startWord = 'the'
endWord = 'string'
results = []

index = 0
while True:
    try:
        startIndex = searchString.index(startWord, index)
        endIndex = searchString.index(endWord, startIndex)

        results.append(searchString[startIndex + len(startWord):endIndex].strip())

        # move the index to the end
        index = endIndex + len(endWord)

    except ValueError:
        # str.index raises a ValueError if there is no match; in that
        # case we know that we’re done looking at the string, so we can
        # break out of the loop
        break

print(results)
# ['initial', 'relevant', 'search']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this:

```
mystring = "this is the initial string"
    mystring = mystring.strip().split(" ")
    for i in range(1,len(mystring)-1):
        if(mystring[i-1] == "the" and mystring[i+1] == "string"):
            print(mystring[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a combination of `list, split` and `join` methods.
This should help if you are looking for more than 1 word in the substring.

1. Turn the string into array:

   `words = list(string.split())`
2. Get the index of your opening and closing markers then return the substring:

   `open = words.index('the')
   close = words.index('string')
   substring = ''.join(words[open+1:close])`

You may want to improve a bit with the checking for the validity before proceeding.

---

If your problem gets more complex, i.e multiple occurrences of the pair values, I suggest using regular expression.

`import re
substring = ''.join(re.findall(r'the (.+?) string', string))`

The `re` should store substrings separately if you view them in `list`.

I am using the spaces between the description to rule out the spaces between words, you can modify to your needs as well.