# Python json scraping i am getting date as 'DueDate': '/Date(1539205200000)/' . I am not getting in date format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

My Json File `'DueDate': '/Date(1539205200000)/', 'Bydate': '/Date(-62135578800000)/', 'NeedsAppointment': False`

Code:

```
for o in odpg:
    try:
        duedate= o['DueDate']
        print(duedate)
    except:
        # Handle error
```

Am getting output as:

```
/Date(1539205200000)/
```

Required Output:

```
07/31/2018
```

Comment: Convert unixtimstamp to datetime using `date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(eval(task_datetime)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` Jus by importing `import datetime`

Comment: Am getting  invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Comment: What _are_ `DueDate` and `ByDate` exactly… the numbers are too big for an epoch and the second number there is negative? Are you sure that your JSON is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct number? At first I thought it’s an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) but that resulted in much too big a year; however, taking away the last three `0`s works which makes me wonder if the epoch is in milliseconds instead of seconds (wild hand-wavy assumption):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(1539205200000))
'50745-06-22 00:00:00'
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(1539205200))
'2018-10-10 21:00:00'
```

or

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1539205200000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: year is out of range
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1539205200)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 11, 7, 0)
```

To produce your desired output, just change the [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> # Assuming constant format "/Date(…)/", this also removes the trailing zeroes..
>>> funky_timestamp = int(o["duedate"][6:-5])
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(funky_timestamp).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'11/10/2018'
```

Comment: exception here
an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Then use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert the string `"1539205200000"` to an integer. But beware the three zeroes and my question, _Are you sure this is the correct number?_

Comment: Am getting the value as **/Date(1539205200000)/**  from json

Comment: I’ve updated my answer: assuming the `o["duedate"]` string is _*always*_ formatted the same way, you can extract the [substring using Python’s slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python).

Comment: @Craze, if this solves your problem then please accept the answer. But beware of my initial question: are you sure that these numbers are [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) values?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import datetime
json = {'DueDate': '/Date(1539205200000)/', 'Bydate': '/Date(-62135578800000)/', 'NeedsAppointment': False}
duedate = re.findall(r'[\d]+', json['DueDate'])
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(duedate[0][:10])).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```