# How to convert the time of a datetime object to an integer?

Tags: python, datetime, integer, seconds

I need the time between two points as integer, to calculate the speed of an object. My first thought was to do it with an datetime object, but I can’t convert it from string to int:

```
from datetime import datetime


#this is already the right format in HH:MM:SS:MS 

d = (datetime.now()).time().isoformat() 
coverted = int(d) # not working because of the ":"
```

i already found an solution here (see below), but the if i print the code, I just get a weird number which doesn't help me at all.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research and a sample input and output

Comment: And what would that integer mean or describe?

Comment: The "weird number that doesn't help you at all" is the number of seconds since 1.1.1970

Comment: @DeepSpace I need the time between two points as integer, to calculate the speed of an object

Comment: @AlfredWächter `timestamp` already gives you time in seconds, so do `timestamp2 - timestamp1`. Don't invent a new way to deal with times because you *will* fail (timezones, leap-years, other fun time-related shenanigans).

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for the explanation, but I need milliseconds as well. Timezones doesn’t matter in my case

Comment: @AlfredWächter So use `datetime.now().timestamp()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First use your date format and cut the strings that you're looking for: (using [Sub-String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python))

```
d = (datetime.now()).time().isoformat()   
min = d[3:-10]
seconds = d[6:-7]
milliseconds = d[9:]
```

Now you can use the `int()` command on your strings to convert them to Integers.
For example:

```
min = int(min)
print min+1
```

Will print the current minute plus one.