# How to extract the last 2 characters of a variable with substring

Tags: python, substring

I need to extract the last two characters of a phrase, but I don't know how as there isn't a minus 0.

Comment: `s[-2:]` works. Note that `s[-1]` *is* the last character in the string, so there is no need for "minus 0" to extract it.

Comment: already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
a = "abcd"
a[-2:]
```

output

```
'cd'
```

By putting a negative number in a string slicing you will get the number of characters from the end of the string.