# remove [edit] from end of string

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with states:

```
Alabama[edit]            8
Alaska[edit]             1
Arizona[edit]            3
Arkansas[edit]
```

Want remove the [edit] from the end of the string.

I tried:
    unit['State'] = unit['State'].str.rstrip('[edit]')
But this code ends up remove the letters edit from the end of state names, e.g Delaware-> Delawar.

How can I remove the exactly [edit]?

Comment: `replace()` will do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
unit['State'] = unit['State'].apply(lambda state : state[:state.index('[edit]')])
```

Comment: Great, works! Could you just briefly explain this part?:
state[:state.index('[edit]')]
Many thanks.

Comment: Sure. we're taking characters of the state from index 0 till just before the start of the string "[edit]". Considering an example like `Arkansas[edit]`, the last character that gets picked up is the last `s` before the `[` . Clear?

Comment: Check this post on [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python) if you're lost on indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
unit.loc[:, 'State'] = [value.split('[edit]')[0].strip() for value in unit.loc[:, 'State']]
```

replace also works as the others have mentioned:

```
unit.loc[:, 'State'] = [value.replace('[edit]', '') for value in unit.loc[:, 'State']]
```

assuming your dataframe is a valid pandas dataframe called "unit" and the desired column label is "State"

For the record, these two methods both outperform the accepted answer:

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
unit["State"] = unit["State"].apply(lambda state: state[: state.index("[edit]")])
print("ACCEPTED ANSWER -> The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
unit.loc[:, 'State'] = [value.split('[edit]')[0] for value in unit.loc[:, 'State']]
print("SPLIT -> The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
unit.loc[:, 'State'] = [value.replace('[edit]', '') for value in unit.loc[:, 'State']]
print("REPLACE -> The time difference is :", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

ACCEPTED ANSWER -> The time difference is : 0.0015293000000000667
SPLIT -> The time difference is : 0.0010911999999998478
REPLACE -> The time difference is : 0.0007515000000002381
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work

```
unit['State'] = unit['State'].str[:-6]
```

Answer (score -1):

One alternative could be to replace the string '[edit]' with ''

```
"Alabama[edit]".replace('[edit]', '')
```

or use slicing

```
"Alabama[edit]"[:-6]
```

both of these options also produce

```
"Alabama"
```

To map it to your request above:

```
unit['State'] = unit['State'].str.replace('[edit'], '')
```

and

```
unit['State'] = unit['State'].str.[:-6]
```

Should both produce the needed output.

Comment: This is incorrect. You forgot to redeclare the variable.

Comment: He is correct in that both lines will produce the output `"Alabama"`.