# Extract string starting with specific string in a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have data as follows

```
[{"ruleId":"RULE","ruleName":"Dependency_rule","ruleDescription":"package rules ; import ava; rule \"M-LC-123 Dependency\" when accountO:Account ( !(Ids contains \"M-LC-456\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-789\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-91011\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-121314\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-1151617\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-181920\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-212223\")) then accO.setBlock(false); end ","ruleType":"DEPEND","ruleExpression":null}]
```

I want to extract all the values which start with M-LC from this.
Example M-LC-123, M-LC-456 and rest all.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a substring of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

`pattern = r"(M-LC-(\d+))"` means "find every occurence of `M-LC-` followed by one or more digits"

```py
import re

data = [{"ruleId":"RULE","ruleName":"Dependency_rule","ruleDescription":"package rules ; import ava; rule \"M-LC-123 Dependency\" when accountO:Account ( !(Ids contains \"M-LC-456\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-789\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-91011\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-121314\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-1151617\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-181920\") && !(Ids contains \"M-LC-212223\")) then accO.setBlock(false); end ","ruleType":"DEPEND","ruleExpression":None}]

data_str = str(data) # prevents need to iterate list/dicts
pattern = r"(M-LC-(\d+))"

results = [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(pattern, data_str)]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['M-LC-123', 'M-LC-456', 'M-LC-789', 'M-LC-91011', 'M-LC-121314', 'M-LC-1151617', 'M-LC-181920', 'M-LC-212223']
```

Comment: amazing it works, can you please explain me the working of pattern and results line, for my understanding?

Comment: @Kimberly_Jennifer there's a lot to learn about regular expressions, I suggest reading the docs page I linked to. basically it's a way to search complex patterns in text, using a special syntax. e.g. `\d` means "any digit", and the `+` means "one or more times".