# how to separate certain parts of a string in python

Tags: python

Lets say i have `myVariable = ‘Hello world’`
How can I get just “World”? Ive tried a bunch of ways.
I am trying to make a chat bot at the moment, and I am making a settings command where you type `:BotSettings` in a input.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a substring of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on space and select element nr 1.

```
myVariable.split(' ')[1]
```

Comment: Ohhh Thanks I have been looking for this

Answer (score 0):

> If I have `myVariable = "Hello World"`, how do I
> make it "World"?

```
myVariable = "World"
```

> If I have `myVariable = "Hello World"`, how do I find the second word?

```
myVariable = myVariable.split()[1] # "World"
```

> If I have `myVariable = "apple Hello World banana"`, how do I find everything written after "Hello"?

```
_, _, myVariable = myVariable.partition("Hello ")
```