# How to remove a single number from input number in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-analytics, data-science, data-science-experience

Here are few example input & outputs to understand the question

example 1

- input  = 555
- output should be  = 55

example 2

- input  = 5455
- output should be  = 545

example 3

- input  = 6555
- output should be  = 655

example 4

- input  = 3675
- output should be  = 367

Kindly help me with code in python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a substring of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: `n = int(str(s)[:-1])`

Answer (score 1):

If those are proper numbers, then `x // 10` (integer division by 10) should do the trick. If they are strings, then `x[:-1]` gets rid of the last character. In both cases `x` is the variable holding the original value.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply divide by 10 and then cast to integer:

```py
inp = [555, 5455, 6555, 3675]
output = [int(x / 10) for x in inp]
print(output)  # [55, 545, 655, 367]
```

The above works if your inputs are actual numbers, and not strings.  If the inputs are *not* strings, then you certainly should not convert them to string first, since the above will perform much faster than a bulky string operation.

Comment: Can we only remove only a single number like 5 from the end if given random number as input?  like      x=input()   x=34567 and output should be 3467

Comment: You are totally changing your original question, which you should not after 2 users have already given answers.  I suggest sticking with your current question, and if you have follow-ups, ask another question later.