# infinite assignment in python list?

Tags: python, list, infinite

I've come cross this question. Code:

```
>>> values = [0, 1, 2]
>>> values[1] = values
>>> values
[0, [...], 2]
```

The result I expect is:

```
[0, [0, 1, 2], 2]
```

Is this an infinite assignment for python list? What is behind the scene?

Thanks.

Comment: no its self reference list

Comment: `What is behind the scene`: read this [Q&A:`What is […] in Python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-is-in-python-2-7/17163521#17163521)

Comment: Your welcome lulyon :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a recursive list there. `values[1]` is a reference to `values`. If you want to store the value of `values` you need to copy it, the easiest way to do so is

```
values[1] = values[:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You put the same list as the second element inside itself. So the second element of the internal list is itself again.

You need to copy initial list to avoid recursion:

```
>>> values[1] = values[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy it:

```
values[1] = values[:]
```

Comment: **Not** Copy, (assign)

Comment: This code is indeed a (shallow) copy, since slicing replicates the list's structure (it does not copy the members though!).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan copy of references maybe?

Comment: @ersran9 Yes, filmor is more correct its called shadow copy actually (not deep copy)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, that's what I meant by copy of references. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @filmor and GrijeshChauhan Would you briefly explain the concept (shallow and deep) copy to me, take my code as an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323689/python-list-slice-syntax-used-for-no-obvious-reason

Comment: @lulyon Look at image here: [Shallow vs. Deep Cloning](http://www.csharp411.com/c-object-clone-wars/)

Comment: @lulyon better: [diagram-1](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/legacy-hpp/docs/tlsug/10.2.html)  [diagram-2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Very instructive diagrams. Deeply greatful!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> values = [0, 1, 2]
>>> values[1] = values
```

you are saying that `values[1]` is `values`, which is `[0, 1, 2]`, with `values` instead of 1, and now `values` is `[0, 1, 2]`, with `values` instead of 1, `[0, 1, 2]`, with `values` instead of 1, `[0, 1, 2]`, with `values` instead of 1,`[0, 1, 2]`, with `values` instead of 1, `[0, 1, 2]`, with `values` instead of 1 ... ... ...