# Python: How to append list values into the list properly?

Tags: python, list

I want to add the values of temp list into the main list. I tried to add some values into the temp list and then append the temp list into the main list as following, but it shows always latest values in the main list.

```
>>> temp =[]
>>> temp.append(123)
>>> temp.append(10)
>>> temp.append(18)
>>> mutR =[]
>>> mutR.append(temp)
>>> print mutR
[[123, 10, 18]]
>>> temp[:]=[]
>>> temp.append(3)
>>> temp.append(4)
>>> temp.append(5)
>>> mutR.append(temp)
>>> print mutR
[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

My expectation is:

```
>>> print mutR
[[123, 10, 18], [3, 4, 5]]
```

but it is `[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]`.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
temp[:] = []
```

removes all the elements from `temp`, what you want to do instead is

```
temp = []
```

that will create a new empty list and store its reference into `temp`.

In your code there is only one list object, added twice to `mutR`, if you add for example

```
temp.append(99)
print mutR
```

to your original code you will see `[[3, 4, 5, 99], [3, 4, 5, 99]]` as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is when you append `temp` to `mutR`, `mutR` contains only **reference** to `temp`. Whatever changes are applied to `temp`, **temp in mutR** will also change accordingly. So, the solution is to use **copy**.

```
>>> temp =[]
>>> temp.append(123)
>>> temp.append(10)
>>> temp.append(18)
>>> mutR =[]
>>> import copy
>>> mutR.append(copy.copy(temp))
>>> print mutR
[[123, 10, 18]]
>>> temp[:]=[]
>>> temp.append(3)
>>> temp.append(4)
>>> temp.append(5)
>>> mutR.append(temp)
>>> print mutR
[[123, 10, 18], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you GO

```
>>> temp =[]
>>> temp.append(123)
>>> temp.append(10)
>>> temp.append(18) 
>>> mutR =[temp]
>>> print(mutR)
[[123, 10, 18]]
>>>
>>>
>>> temp=[]
>>> temp.append(3)
>>> temp.append(4)
>>> temp.append(5)
>>> mutR.append(temp)
>>> print(mutR)
[[123, 10, 18], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `extend` method.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This helps but I want to keep the bracket like this [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]. I want to use it like this l[0] (=[1,2,3]), l[1] (=[4,5,6])

Answer (score 0):

`mutR.append(temp)` appends  temp to `mutR`, `temp[:]=[]` makes `temp` an empty list again, the `temp` in `mutR` also becomes an empty list as it is a **reference** to `temp` **not** a **copy**.

Then you append three elements to the empty temp and add `temp` to `mutR` with  `mutR.append(temp)` so you have two **references** to `temp` in your list.

Use  `mutR.append(temp[:]) # <- copy of temp  not a reference` initially to add a copy of `temp`to `mutR` so later changes to temp won't affect it.

```
In [6]: mutR.append(temp[:])   # copy temp  
In [7]: temp[:]=[]    
In [8]: temp.append(3)    
In [9]:  temp.append(4)    
In [10]: temp.append(5)    
In [11]: mutR.append(temp)    
In [12]: mutR
Out[12]: [[123, 10, 18], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: I prefer explicitly invoking `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy` to using slicing to create a new object

Comment: @AdamSmith, that is down to personal preference, it is not necessary when dealing with a single list

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `temp[]=[]` rather than `temp[:]=[]`

See also : [Python list slice syntax used for no obvious reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323689/python-list-slice-syntax-used-for-no-obvious-reason)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much nothing in Python makes a copy unless it explicitly says it makes a copy. In particular, `append` doesn't make a copy; any changes to the object you append will be reflected in the list you appended it to, because the list is holding a reference to the original object.

To avoid problems like this, don't clear out an existing object when you want a new one. Instead, create a new object:

```
temp = []
```

instead of

```
temp[:] = []
```

I suppose if you really want to clear the original `temp` list instead of replacing it, you could instead make a copy when you append:

```
mutR.append(temp[:])
```