# list.append(another_list) vs list.append(another_list[:]) in python?

Tags: python, list, append

Here is a problem I had to do:

We are going to implement a very helpful function, called group.

group takes a list of things and returns a list of group, where each group is formed by all equal consecutive elements in the list.

For example:

group([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1]) == [[1, 1, 1], [2], [3], [1, 1]]

group([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3]) == [[1], [2], [1], [2], [3, 3]]

And here is my initial solution:

```
def group(int_list):    

group_list = []
current_list = []

for i in range(len(int_list)):
    if int_list[i] not in current_list:
        if len(current_list) != 0:
            group_list.append(current_list)
        del current_list[:]
        current_list.append(int_list[i])
    else:
        current_list.append(int_list[i])    

group_list.append(current_list)

return group_list
```

And the output I was getting:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

After spending like 30 minutes trying to figure out the problem, I changed the 9th line from `group_list.append(current_list)` to `group_list.append(current_list[:])` and surprisingly the magic worked. I got the correct output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2], [3], [1, 1]]
```

So I guess my question is what's the difference between `current_list` and `current_list[:]` ?

Comment: Another way to fix the original code is to change `del current_list[:]` to `current_list = []`, this way the next time you append `current_list` it's going to be a different list (i.e. no need to make a shallow copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_list[:]` is a *shallow copy* of `current_list`; e.g.,:

- [Introducing lists: Slicing shorthand](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html#odbchelper.list.slicing.example)
- [Python list slice syntax used for no obvious reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323689/python-list-slice-syntax-used-for-no-obvious-reason)
- ["copying a list the right way"](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list)

In your function, you're building up a list (of the current group) in the thing referred to by `current_list`.  When you're done, you add this thing to `group_list`, and then reset the thing by deleting all of its contents (`del current_list[:]`).  We have to remember that everything in Python is a reference, so, using your first code, `group_list` contains several references to the *same object* (this is why your output looks like `[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]`).  When you delete the contents of `current_list` and add new elements later on, you do this to every element of `group_list`, too.

Using the `current_list[:]` syntax that you discovered, you create a copy of `current_list` and add this onto `group_list`; this copy is not modified later when you delete the contents of `current_list`.

Comment: So is this the correct way to do it? Just by adding [:]

Comment: @BobbyBrown it seems the consensus is that, in terms of code style, it's clearer to create shallow copies by writing `list(current_list)` than `current_list[:]`.  This is just aesthetics, though; creating copies with the slice operator works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly the main difference is that current_list is the reference to the list, and current_list[:] is a new array with the elements of the list. So, using the first one, when you change current_list, group_list is also changed. The other way if you change current_list, group_list is not modified.